# HiveQL: build a pairwise comparison table

Tags: sql, hiveql

I am trying to build a Hive table that contains pairwise comparisons of `ids`. For example, let's say we start with table `A`:

```
id  val
a   10
b   11
c   12
```

I want to create a table `B`:

```
id_A  id_B  val_A  val_B  val_diff
a     b     10     11     -1
a     c     10     12     -2
b     c     11     12     -1
```

I believe this requires a self-join, but I'm not sure how to do it. Any ideas or leads to follow are appreciated.

I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE C STORED AS ORC AS
SELECT a.id         AS id_A, 
       b.id         AS id_B,
       a.val         AS val_A,
       b.val         AS val_B,
       a.val - b.val AS val_diff
FROM A AS a
INNER JOIN B as b
ON a.id != b.id;
```

but it did not work:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 4:3 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'id'
```

**UPDATE:**
problem extension.

Suppose I have table `A'`:

```
id  val  category
a   10   X
b   11   X
c   12   X
d   13   Y
e   14   Y
f   15   Y
```

How would I do a pairwise comparison only among elements of each `category`?

I.e. a table `B'`:

```
id_A  id_B  val_A  val_B  val_diff cat
a     b     10     11     -1       X
a     c     10     12     -2       X
b     c     11     12     -1       X
d     e     . . .                  Y
d     f     . . .                  Y
e     f     . . .                  Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a self join:

```
select a.id as id_a, b.id as id_b, a.val as val_a, b.val as val_b,
       (a.val - b.val) as val_diff
from t a join
     t b
     on a.id < b.id;
```

In Hive, you might need to do:

```
select a.id as id_a, b.id as id_b, a.val as val_a, b.val as val_b,
       (a.val - b.val) as val_diff
from t a cross join
     t b
where a.id < b.id;
```

Comment: how does this inequality compare strings? not sure how to read it ("join where a less than b"?) also, from a purely coding semantics perspective, wouldn't `on a.id <> b.id` be more interpretable (I know it doesn't work)?

Comment: You want each combination of id, not each permutation.  In your example you have a,b,c.  So you have (a,b), (a,c), and (b,c).  Since (b,c) is the same as (c,b) you really don't need all permutations.  Furthermore if this is hive you might have to put that a.id < b.id in your WHERE clause, since hive does not support non-equi joins.  (so do a cross join basically and filter the rows out you don't want)

Comment: @deusxmach1na Is there any way to avoid a cross-join? It seems computationally expensive, especially since my real use case involves a table with billions of unique `id`. Could be my compute cluster speed as well, but the job has been running for several days now.

Comment: @user2205916 . . . I would suggest that you ask the "extended" question as a new question and ask about performance there.